# Emulate Zebra Printer for Zebra Browser Print

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, printers

I am building an app that uses [Zebra's Browser Print SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/browser-print.html) to print barcode labels via the browser. Currently, I don't have access to a compatible Zebra printer, on the machine that I am developing this app on.

Can you think of a way to emulate a Zebra printer in such a way that the Browser Print SDK picks it up, so I can pretend to print from a browser?

What I tried so far:

- I installed different Zebra Printer Drivers that were said to be compatible. The Browser Print SDK doesn't pick up these installed printers though.
- Looked into  using Chrome and the extension [ZPL Printer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zpl-printer/phoidlklenidapnijkabnfdgmadlcmjo/support?hl=en-US)
- Set up a generic/text printer per [Zebra's instructions](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=WH70&actp=LIST)

Neither option populated the list in Zebra's Browser Print window of available printers. Is the only way of getting a printer to show up, to buy a Browser Print compatible Zebra printer and hook it up to my workstation?

Comment: Hi @jm Were you ever able to figure this issue out?  I'm trying to use Browser Print with the ZPL Printer Chrome Extension and I'm seeing exactly what you are seeing.  Did you have to buy a printer to get Browser Print to work correctly?  I can actually print to the Zpl printer from the command line so I know that the ZPL Printer Extension is working correctly but I cant get it to show up in Browser Print.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:
Install the Browser Print native application from these (unofficial) locations:
Windows: https://zebra.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/ZXT-CustomSolutions/EamMe3ubWUVJmycCLPEBAqIBX8a7Jsf9kEuHNnAmLMcMow?e=8Uux7c
Mac: https://zebra.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/ZXT-CustomSolutions/ES0NSZ780Z9MjOjfwxQSEpQBVSOZhtXRm2_Axvn9DaS5fQ?e=2EhKjC

Then install the Chrome Plugin named “Zpl Printer”, and configure it to listen on a port such as 9102 (Browser Print took 9100 & 9101).

On Browser Print click on “Manage” (next to “Added Devices”) and configure the Chrome Plugin IP (127.0.0.1) and port (9102).

Open zebra-browser-print-js-v30216/sample/index.html and under “Selected Device” pick the name you gave your “Added Device” and click on “Send ZPL Label”. The Chrome Plugin should display “Test Label”.
[image: illustration]

Comment: I received the same links from customsolutions@zebra.com so i guess they might be official locations ? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well hell, that link has expired. Anyone have a fresh link or somewhere to d/l that content?

Answer (score 0):

Install Zebra Designer to have a list of driver that you can use:

Try to create a driver that is using ff:

-COM
-LPT
-USB

or try to use Javascript third party app that you won't needed this  **Zebra's Browser Print SDK**

Trust me , you will need a lot time by using their SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK for mac actually hides the "Device Address" input label. So be sure to put device address (127.0.0.1) after the device name
[Adding Printer on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyjed.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and quickly wrote an emulator that allows the Browser Print SDK to work.  It doesn't show what will be printed as an image, but outputs the ZPL itself (which can be loaded into online viewers).  It has saved me a lot of paper!
https://github.com/brianzinn/zebra-emulator